# How to align text in a multiline Discord embed?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I have an embed with a long string that breaks the line. Since I am numbering each line the alignment is off. How can I correct this? ***I used \n to break the line for example purposes***

This is currently how the embed looks

[image]

I would like to indent the second line to make the text look like:

1. this is a long

   string

**My Code:**

```
command(client, 'title' , (message) => {

 const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()

    .setTitle('Title')
    .setColor('#C69B6D')
    .addFields(
       {
       name: 'Field' ,
       value: "1: this is a long \n string",
       inline: true,
       },
    )
 
 message.channel.send(embed).then(msg => {})
 
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found a somewhat "fix". If I use a code block; I can then use a string literal and force the line break where the string becomes too long then add spaces.

My embed now looks like

[image]

**My Updated Code:**

````
command(client, 'title' , (message) => {

 const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()

    .setTitle('Title')
    .setColor('#C69B6D')
    .addFields(
       {
       name: 'Field' ,
       value: "```1: this is a long \n   string```",
       inline: true,
       },
    )
 
 message.channel.send(embed).then(msg => {})
 
})
````

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is formally not supported without 'cheating' with spaces.
I dont know if the string is of custom length, but if it is a constant string, just add in spaces where necessary:

```js
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('Title')
    .setColor('#C69B6D')
    .addFields(
    {
       name: 'Field' ,
       value: "1: this is a long \n    string", //adding 4 spaces will indent your string
       inline: true,
    },
);
```

I'm thinking of a way you could achieve this with a function that iterates through your string adding spaces where necessary but for what it is, it seems like unnecessary hassle